# Proving two lines have the same length

Tags: geometry, circles

**Problem**

Given two circles $ \Gamma_1 $ and $ \Gamma_2 $ which intersect each other at point $ V $. A line $ \ell $ intersects $ \Gamma_2 $ at point $ K $ and intersects $ \Gamma_1 $ at points $ A $ and $ B $. If $ KV $ intersects $ \Gamma_1 $ again at point $ S $, prove that $ SA = SB $.

**My Attempt**

[image: Geometric construction]

My approach was to extend the line segment $ AV $ and $ BV $ so that it intersects $ \Gamma_2 $ at $ F $ and $ H $, respectively.

I managed to prove that $ \triangle{ABS} $ and $ \triangle{KHF} $ are similar. If we can prove that $ KF \parallel AS $, then $ SB \parallel KH $ and $ AB \parallel FH $. Hence, $ \angle{BAS} = \angle{KFH} = \angle{AKF} = \angle{KHF} = \angle{SBA} $ and we proved that $ SB = SA $. But I have a problem while proving $ KF \parallel AS $. I have tried to prove it by the fact that $ \angle{AKF} = \angle{KHF} $, but it doesn't seem to work.

My question is, how is it supposed to prove $ AS \parallel KF $ (or maybe there is another way to attack this problem)?

Thank you.

Comment: You have allready proved that the triangles $ABS$ and $KHV$ are similar. Probably you used the fact that the triangles $VAS$ and $VFK$ are similar. This implies $KF\parallel AS$.

Comment: Yes, of course if $ \triangle{VAS} $ and $ \triangle{VFK} $ are similar, then it will implies $ 
KF \parallel AS $, but how do we prove that these two triangles are similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw line segment $SP$ and extend to meet $AB$. Say it meets $AB$ at $H$.

Now in $\triangle QKV$, as $KQ = QV$, $\angle KVQ = \angle QKV$

In $\triangle KHS$,

$\angle HSK = \angle PVS = \angle KVQ = \angle QKV$ (as $PS = PV$)

Also, $\angle HKS = 90^0 - \angle QKV$

So $\angle KHS = 90^0$. As $SH$ passing through the center of the circle is perpendicular to chord $AB$, it must bisect $AB$ and we show that $\triangle ASB$ is isosceles with $SA = SB$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider triangles $PVA$ and $QVF$. They are similar isosceles triangles. It follows:
$
\frac{VA}{VF}=\frac{VP}{VQ}.
$

By the similar argument:
$$
\frac{VA}{VF}=\frac{VB}{VH}=\frac{VS}{VK}=\frac{VP}{VQ}.
$$

From this
$$
\triangle AVS\sim\triangle FVK\implies AS\parallel FK.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but did you mean $ \triangle{PVS} $ instead of $ \triangle{PVQ} $?

Comment: @Anggalol I meant $PVA$. Thanks for catching his.